# How to change super + space menu item position to stay consistent?

Tags: 22.04, language-support, menu

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. When using super+space to switch languages, the small menu that pops up in the middle of the screen always has the current language centered, meaning that the position of the items in the menu changes depending on the selected language. I would prefer that the positions of the menu items would stay consistent regardless of the currently chosen language, so it would be easier to tell which language I'm currently on. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Actually the layout you used next before the current one is focused. But no, I don't think there is an option to change that. It would be a different design idea and would probably require code changes.